# file doesn't want to be parse ( app.yaml Google Cloud Platoform - App Engine context )

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml

I wanted to add a http headers access control allow origin to make my app compatible with CORS. I did it in the app.yaml file but when I try to deploy my server, it make me a parsing error.

> An error occurred while parsing file

Here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

skip_files:
  - ^node_modules$

handlers:
  - url: /generate
    http_headers:
      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http:/localhost:3000
```

Do someone have an idea please ? I think that I have respect the indentation.

Thanks :)

Comment: Trying putting a `-` (dash) before `http_headers`

Comment: I tried, but still doesn't working  :/ In the gcp docs it's on my way I've to write it

Comment: You are missing a `/` in your url: `http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the parsing error you need to include the [directory of the shared resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_http_headers):

```
handlers:
- url: /generate
  static_dir: static/whatever
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
```